# CMake doesn't link correctly?

Tags: c++, linker, cmake

I am currently trying to debug a program, which is rather determined to not run. I guess the mistake is rather simple, I am really new to c++ and using cmake.

Here is the error message:

```
Scanning dependencies of target viewer

[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/Main.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/TriangleMesh.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/Camera.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable viewer
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::mousePressed(int, int, int, int): error: undefined reference
to 'MainWindow::mouse_button'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::mousePressed(int, int, int, int): error: undefined reference
to 'MainWindow::mouse_state'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::render(): error: undefined reference to 'MainWindow::cam'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::render(): error: undefined reference to 'MainWindow::mesh'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::mouseMove(int, int): error: undefined reference to
'MainWindow::mouse_button'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::mouseMove(int, int): error: undefined reference to
'MainWindow::old_y'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::mouseMove(int, int): error: undefined reference to
'MainWindow::old_x'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::mouseMove(int, int): error: undefined reference to
'MainWindow::cam'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::mouseMove(int, int): error: undefined reference to
'MainWindow::cam'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::mouseMove(int, int): error: undefined reference to
'MainWindow::mouse_button'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::mouseMove(int, int): error: undefined reference to
'MainWindow::old_x'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::mouseMove(int, int): error: undefined reference to
'MainWindow::old_y'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::mouseMove(int, int): error: undefined reference to
'MainWindow::mouse_button'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::mouseMove(int, int): error: undefined reference to
'MainWindow::cam'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::MainWindow(Camera*, int, char**): error: undefined reference
to 'MainWindow::old_x'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::MainWindow(Camera*, int, char**): error: undefined reference
to 'MainWindow::old_y'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::MainWindow(Camera*, int, char**): error: undefined reference
to 'MainWindow::mesh'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::MainWindow(Camera*, int, char**): error: undefined reference
to 'MainWindow::mesh'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::MainWindow(Camera*, int, char**): error: undefined reference
to 'MainWindow::mesh'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::getInstance(Camera*, int, char**): error: undefined reference
to 'MainWindow::instance'
CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o:MainWindow.cpp:function
MainWindow::getInstance(Camera*, int, char**): error: undefined reference
to 'MainWindow::instance'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [viewer] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/viewer.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So, the code compiles just fine, it just cannot really link one of the 4 source files..

#### Edit:

Here is the gist of MainWindow.hpp

```
class MainWindow
{
        private:
                MainWindow() {}
                MainWindow(const MainWindow&) {}
                MainWindow(Camera *cam, int argc, char* argv[]);
                static MainWindow *instance;
                static Camera *cam;
                static TriangleMesh mesh;
                static int old_x;
                static int old_y;
                static int mouse_button;
                static int mouse_state;
                static void mousePressed(int button, int state, int x, int y);
                static void initGlut(int argc, char* argv[]);
                static void initCallbacks();
                static void render();
                static void reshape(int w, int h);
                static void keyPressed(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
                static void mouseMove(int x, int y);

        public:
                static MainWindow* getInstance(Camera *cam, int argc, char* argv[]);
                static void setCamera(Camera* cam);
                static void setMesh(TriangleMesh* mesh);
                static void destroy();
};
```

Comment: Do he `MainWindow` class _have_ those members? How are they declared? How are they defined?

Comment: That's what I checked first. But they defenitely do, and i think the includes are fine as well. The thing is, all object files are compiled niceley, so i guess they are found, too. Just not by the linker. 
edit: added the declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have static member variables, they need to be *defined* as well, not only *declared*:

In a header file:

```
class Foo
{
    ...

    // This declares a static member variable
    static int static_member_variable;

    ...
};
```

In a source file:

```
// This defines the variable
int Foo::static_member_variable;
```

Comment: You mean, in order to define lets say, old_x in the .cpp file, it's not enough to write
`old_x = 0;` , but `int MainWindow::old_x = 0;` ?

Comment: @ArneRecknagel Yes, otherwise you just declare a normal global variable.

Comment: Thank you so much - I never would have guessed that static member variables were my problem. I needed some time to figure out that the declaration has to be put at the top of the source file, but now that that's done, everything works as fine as I can expect it to. =)